# What if \\Server\Folder1 and \\Server\Folder2 requires different user accounts?

Tags: windows, samba, network-drive

OK, I think this is a plausible scenario.
Let us assume that there is a Server, and it has Folder1 and Folder2.
Folder1 allows only user1 to access itself, and Folder2 allows only user2.

Now suppose I try to use `\\Server\Folder1` and `\\Server\Folder2` at the same time from a single client PC. What is the best way? Little Google search gave me that I have to map each folder to a network drive, but that solution is really clumsy if there are 30 folders in the `\\Server` and they require different user accounts.

The most idea solution could be Windows allows logging in to `\\Server` with multiple accounts at the same time...

[Edit]
Please. We all know how to save credentials for one account. I mean MULTIPLE ACCOUNTS AT THE SAME TIME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply, windows does not support multiple simultaneous connections to the same server using different credentials.

See this [technet discussion](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f3ee2c61-a5c7-48b3-a3bf-23ea323da699/connecting-to-multiple-shares-on-a-single-server-with-multiple-credentials-system-error-1219-) or Knowledge Base article [938120](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938120) for more details.

See this [Server Fault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/57877/system-error-1219-has-occurred) for ways to change out credentials with `net use`

Comment: OK, just as I suspected... If there is no other way, I have to give up and look for other ways such as FTP. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to create a single shared folder. E.g. create \server\home\ with two sub folders.

```
\\server\home\folder1  
\\server\home\folder2
```

Then use NTFS ACLs to limit who can access which folder, and log in with an AD account.

You would end up with a single shared folder (\server\home) which can be shared/accessed by everyone. And sub folders which will deny permission to people not in the right group.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has an inbuilt credential manager, where you can go to populate and manage existing remembered credentials.

More info from Microsoft: [What is Credential Manager?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows7/what-is-credential-manager)

Blurb:

> Credential Manager allows you to store credentials, such as user names
>   and passwords that you use to log on to websites or other computers on
>   a network. By storing your credentials, Windows can automatically log
>   you on to websites or other computers.

Comment: No, it does not work. In the "Internet or network address" field I typed "Server\Folder1" but Windows ignored the folder path and just saved it for "Server". I added a new credential with "Server\Folder2", and this time it overwrote the previous credential for "Server\Folder1".